# Change of data in UITableViewCell while Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The value of the label in UITableviewcell is changing when scrolled.I checked a few answers on the net.But I am not able to find the answer.Here is my code

```
 -(void)configureCell:(ScoreViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Player *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = player.playerName;
    cell.totalScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",player.currentScore];
    [cell.enterScoreField setTag:indexPath.row];
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"addScoreCell";
    ScoreViewCell *cell = (ScoreViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if ((cell == nil) ||  (![cell isKindOfClass: [ScoreViewCell class]])) {

        cell = [[ScoreViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier]; 
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What are the other places you call `configureCell` at ?

Comment: Are you modifying self.players  anywhere else?

Comment: @A-Live As of now only here

Comment: @ShantiK no i am not modifying it anywhere else

Comment: @Sekhar.. Both the labels change on scrolling?

Comment: Then having another method is kind of useless...  When you say data is changing, nameLabel takes another player name for instance ?

Comment: @ShantiK Only the totalScoreLabel is changing.

Comment: @Justafinger name label is not changing only the other label is changing.its going back to 0.

Comment: Put a NSLog at the point where you are setting the totalScoreLabel. And log player.currentScore. Check what it logs when u scroll

Comment: Do you implement prepareForReuse ?

Comment: @ShantiK Its showing 0. Now I got it.I am not saving it right?.

Comment: Check how currentScroe is being set. My doubt is that the currentScore in the Player object itself is 0.

Comment: @ShantiK right its showing 0.thanks a lot shanti.... i will take care of it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how `currentScroe` is being set in your code. Check if it gets modified elsewhere. I doubt that the currentScore in the Player object itself is 0.